# HTML PHP FORM two actions?

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a HTML form where after the user submits the form they see my FormSubmit.php thank you page. Is there a way to make that thank you page still display after submission, but also add a link to another php page that shows you a list of who added their names? 
I created a SignupList.php page that reads from a text file. I added the link to the form HTML page at the bottom and to the FormSubmit.php thank you page, but when I add a name ,reach my FormSubmit.php thank you page, then click the link to my SignupList.php page there are no names on it. I noticed on the HTML page in the form action section when I replace FormSubmit.php with SignupList.php I get my desired results a name displays after hitting submit, but my thank you page is gone since I removed the action to it. Any suggestions on how I can do both? Please let me know if I need to explain further.

```
 <!DOCType html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Form</title>
            <html lang="en">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylesheet.css">
        </head>
        <body>
          <form method="post" action="FormSubmit.php"> 
              <p>Please sign up</p>
              <p> First Name:<br>
                 <input type="text" name="firstname" size="30">
              </p>
              <p> Last Name:<br>
                 <input type="text" name= "last name" size="30">
              </p>
              <p>
             <input type="submit" value="Submit Information">
             </p>
             <a href="SignupList.php">View Sign Ups</a>
          </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

edit: I am not sure why i was down voted, but i figured out the issue. I needed to edit my FormSubmit.php file to write to the document.

Comment: This isn't entirely clear. A form can only have one action, but you can do as many things as you like when you process the form. If you're wanting to store a list of names for retrieval later, you need a database (or at least some other form of persistent storage, like a text file).

Answer (score 0):

In your `Formsubmit.php`, add:

```
header('Refresh: 3;url=page.php');
```

which will refresh the header and redirect the page after 3 seconds.